# New Windows 10 tablet is never prompted for password to access shared folder on Debian host. "Access is denied"

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, credentials

I have a new Windows 10 tablet that I'm trying to access some network shares with. My host is a debian PC that works fine for sharing three folders to other Windows 10 clients... I don't believe the problem is with the host.

**On this new tablet, I'm never prompted for my credentials when trying to access the shared folders.** I can browse to the host PC, but I get the "access denied" error message as soon as I double-click on one of the shared folders.

[screen shot showing shared folders but no access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksqgY.jpg)

All other clients get prompted for their password.

**update:**

Followed this thread and now get prompted for login name and password: [In Windows 8.1, how to force prompt for credentials when accessing a shared folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/722153/in-windows-8-1-how-to-force-prompt-for-credentials-when-accessing-a-shared-fold?rq=1)

After entering `net use` in the power shell, I saw that credentials for the networked drives were already saved. There must have been a previous attempt from the client tablet to connect.

Purging the saved table with `net use * /DELETE` results in being prompted for credentials to access shared folders.

Access is still denied, but I think I'll need to start a new question.

Answer (score -1):

purge the saved credentials with `net use * /DELETE` from within Power Shell.

results in being prompted for login credentials when attempting to access shared folders.